# Socket ObjectInputStream not working after deploy

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming, lan

i'm creating a client(android)/server(java) program and the problem is everything works in LAN but when i put my jar on server it gets stuck on creating the ObjectInputStream object.

here is client piece:

```
       oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
       oos.flush();
       ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
```

and the server:

```
       oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
       oos.flush();
       ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

so both are equal.
i also tried without the flushes and also switching the ObjectOutputStream creation with the ObjectInputStream in the client.
everything works in LAN. seems pretty logical. but not over internet.

thanks!

Comment: What doesn't work over the Internet?   Can it connect?  Does it work if you don't use an object stream? I suspect it is nothing to do with code.

Comment: sockets on both sides are created i print client socket out when anyone connects but it gets stuck on the 'ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());' line. it works with dataInputStream but terminates while writing to the socket. i prefer Objects  though.

Comment: What do you mean by; terminates while writing to the socket.

Comment: DataInputstream and dataOutputStream are working fine in LAN. but on server somehow the receiver reads -1 while reading. i send the length first and read that much from the stream.

Comment: if you are reading -1 that means you wrote -1. No way this would randomly happen consistently like that.

Comment: Btw you can write arrays and collections like List. Don't need to send a length before multiple objects.

Comment: How does 'terminates while writing' relate to 'receiver read -1 while reading'? The code you posted does not behave as you have described. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: i send length when i use DataStreams. of course i can send whatever in the object streams but they are not working properly as i said. sorry the read method returns -1.

Comment: read method returns -1 cause socket closes on one side i don't why